# What tech/protocols to livestream multiple, synchronized videos to web client?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, rtsp, http-live-streaming

Imagine the security operator scenario, in a browser:

- multiple cameras streaming in real-time from a facility: they will be "pushing" video (probably via RTP) to... something, depending on what has to happen to make it ingestible by operator browser app)
- at least a single remote operator viewing some number of those streams, synchronized in a browser.

**What are options here in terms of technology, protocols etc, for a pipeline to deliver from camera to operator's browser in near real-time** (preferably under 2s)? What's the state of the art today?

My understanding is:

- browsers are generally not able to ingest realtime protocols (RTSP etc)
- WebRTC is not good at large numbers of video sources (4-8 potentially), and sesion management would be weird with arbitrary streams going to cloud to be consumed in one or more different browser sessions (please convince me otherwise if I'm wrong!)
- HLS would need some really aggressive "hacking around" its latency issues with short segments, specific encoding options, and also only appears to work well in Safari?
- what else?  I don't know what I don't know :-)

Comment: your understanding of WebRTC assumes a "full mesh" architecture. WebRTC can use a server too.

Comment: For some reason I thought that the browser client itself could only have some small number open at once.  It seems I may have been wrong about that. I assumed I will have a media server ingesting RTP streams before wiring them up to consumers via... whatever else, including possibly webrtc.  In this case, for a browser playing back 8 streams the question might be how many peer connections to have, managing a single connection or having a session per stream (the latter possibly being cleaner, architecturally?)